# Shared Modules in a Django project

Tags: django, django-models

Based on some advises, I created a separate folder in my Django project with ***init***.py to put all the shared classes and functions in one place.

I tried to import them using ..folder.module but it doesn't work.

What's the right method for sharing class and functions in a Django project?

Comment: Aside from models, which have to be available from `<app>/models.py` (or `<app>/models/__init__.py`), there's nothing special to how Django works c.f. Python. What error do you get? How does it "not work"?

Comment: Also, what's your module structure?

Comment: I'm new to this language and framework, so not sure whether I'm doing it right or not. I created a separate folder, at the same level as I have the others like "templates", put an __init__ to make it a package and then tried to call it in a views.py for an app I created and installed in Django.